# Performance trade off of using a rectangular shaped texture vs. square shaped texture in Three.js material? Specifically a .basis texture

Tags: three.js, gpu, textures

I'm wondering what the trade off is between using a texture that's 128x512 vs. a texture that's 512x512.

The texture is a skateboard deck (naturally rectangular) so I initially made the texture have an aspect ratio that made the deck appear correctly.

I'd like to use a .basis texture and read "Transcoding to PVRTC1 (for iOS) requires **square** power-of-two textures." on the [Three.js BasisTextureLoader documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/BasisTextureLoader).

So I'm trying to weigh the loading time + performance trade off between using the 128x512 as a JPG or PNG vs. a 512x512 basis texture.

My best guess is that the 128x512 would take up less memory because less texels but I've also read that the GPU likes square textures and basis is much more GPU optimized, so I'm torn between which route to take here.

Any knowledge of the performance trade offs between these two options would be highly appreciated, especially an explanation of the benfits of basis textures in general.

Comment: "*I've also read that the GPU likes square textures*" Citation needed

Comment: I guess this was an old paradigm but https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/404768-square-vs-rectangular-textures/. Also the fact that PVRTC1 (for iOS) requires a square

Comment: In the question you cited, many of the users didn't seem to recognize that the question was asking about POT textures that were rectangular in shape and not the D3D/OpenGL concept of a "[rectangle texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rectangle_Texture)". Most of the answers pertain to the latter, not the former.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for letting me know - I've edited this title to be more clear

Comment: What is a "basis texture"?

Comment: @gman "Basis texture" is a [newer method of texture compression](https://www.khronos.org/blog/google-and-binomial-contribute-basis-universal-texture-format-to-khronos-gltf-3d-transmission-open-standard) that's more efficient than JPG or PNG.

Comment: Marquizzo is correct and here's the link to the basis github https://github.com/BinomialLLC/basis_universal

Answer (score 1):

Three.js only really needs power-of-two textures when you're asking the [texture's `.minFilter`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture.minFilter) to perform mip-mapping. In this case, the GPU will make [several copies of the texture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap#Mechanism) at half the resolution as the previous one (512, 256, 128, 64, etc...) which is why it asks for a power-of-two. The default value does perform mip-mapping, you can see alternative `.minFilter` values [in this page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/constants/Textures) under "Minification Filters". `Nearest` and `Linear` do not require P.O.T. textures, but you'll get pixellization artifacts when the texture is scaled down.

In WebGL, you can use a 512x128 without problems, since both dimensions are a power-of-two. The perfomance tradeoff is that you save a bunch of pixels that would have been stretched-out duplicates anyway.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with mip maps but you said the default value does create mip maps. Is there any way to see those in action? In other words, am I able to check which mip map is being used on a specific mesh during a specific frame? Does the GPU switch which mip map it's using according to distance from the camera, pixel space the mesh takes up on the canvas, or something else?

Comment: I believe the GPU generates the mipmaps automatically when a texture gets uploaded to it with the appropriate `minFilter` flag. Then it decides which mip level to use when you're sampling a texture via `texture2D()` in the fragment shader. You can't really check which mip level is being used per mesh; [think of a complex mesh](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals), the parts that are closer to the camera will sample larger mip levels, whereas the parts that are further away sample smaller ones in the same drawcall. Sometimes it may even use a blend of two levels for the same pixel.

Comment: On second thought, you *could* check which mip level each fragment is using if [you create your own `.mipmaps` array](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture.mipmaps) and attach it to the texture. You could use a different color for each level so you could visualize which pixel is sampling which.